# Using config.entities_additional with a backslash \ (#92) is breaking it

Tags: javascript, regex, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

We want to use `config.entities_additional` to replace all occurrences of the ASCII backslash to its numeric form, `&#92;`

However, when using the following config:

```
config.entities_additional = "#92";
```

... it breaks the ckeditor.

We get...

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   /[ ><&"­¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿×÷ƒ•…′″‾⁄℘ℑℜ™ℵ←↑→↓↔↵⇐⇑⇒⇓⇔∀∂∃∅∇∈∉∋∏∑−∗√∝∞∠∧∨∩∪∫∴∼≅≈≠≡≤≥⊂⊃⊄⊆⊇⊕⊗⊥⋅⌈⌉⌊⌋⟨⟩◊♠♣♥♦ˆ˜   ‌‍‎‏–—‘’‚“”„†‡‰‹›€ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿŒœŠšŸΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψωϑϒϖ]/:
>   Unterminated character class

We have tried escaping the backslash with the following code:

```
config.entities_additional = "\\#92";
```

... but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions or tips on how we can achieve this with ckeditor?

Thank you for your help in advance.

**UPDATE:**
We have tried the options in the comments below suggested by Wiktor but neither work.

```
config.entities_additional = "#92#92";
```

... does nothing at all, the backslashes are still not converted:
[image]

```
config.entities_additional = "\\x5C";
```

... seems to break the editor and when switching from code mode to editor mode, we get this:
[image]

Comment: What happened to the post comments below here?  Why have they been removed?

Comment: [It is stated](https://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.entities_additional) that there must be a list of comma-separated values and a single quote is default. Really, no idea why that does not work. `config.entities_additional = '#92,#39';` should be working, but probably there is some bug in the [parsing code](https://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/src/plugins_entities_plugin.js.html).

Comment: Thanks, Wicktor.  Is there any patch/workaround we can use?

Comment: If you can get to the underlying code, make sure you add `"\\\\"` to the `RegExp` constructor. I do not know how it can be solved.